# Android: Scheduled Notification doesn't show up?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, android-notifications

I am basically trying to show a daily notification at a scheduled time (for example: 7:30 AM everyday). However, the code I implemented doesn't show a notification at all.

**The Activity where I set the time:**

```
//This method is called by a button onClick method
private void SaveData() {
        //I get the hour, minute and the AM/PM from 3 edittexts
        String hours = hoursBox.getText().toString();
        String minutes = minutesBox.getText().toString();
        String ampm = ampmBox.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if (hours.length() != 0 && minutes.length() != 0 && ampm.length() != 0) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hours));
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(minutes));
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            //calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

            Intent intent=new Intent(this, ReminderService.class);
            AlarmManager manager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,intent, 0);
            manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),24*60*60*1000,pendingIntent);
        }
 }
```

**ReminderService.java**

```
public class ReminderService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Intent resultIntent=new Intent(this, Dashboard.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,resultIntent,0);


        Notification noti_builder= new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Hello from the other side!")
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.helloicon)
                .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        noti_builder.flags |=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(1,noti_builder);

    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Should I add anything to the manifest as well? These are the only two implementations I have right now. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "...the code I implemented doesn't show a notification at the scheduled time." - Do you mean it doesn't show at all, or just not at the desired time?

Comment: Doesn't show at all @MikeM.

Comment: Do you have the `Service` listed in the manifest?

Comment: Oh no I haven't! What should I add? @MikeM.

Comment: Inside the `<application>` tags, where your `<activity>` is listed: `<service android:name="ReminderService" />`.

Comment: Okay I added that but still no luck @MikeM. Is that code line correct? Should I mention something like 'Receiver'? I saw it on some other stackoverflow threads

Comment: Your code is correct. You're not using a Receiver, so you don't need that. I might not've been clear, but the `<service>` should not be inside the `<activity>`. Also, with my example `<service>` line, the `Service` class should be in the same folder as the `Activity`. And, you're using the `setRepeating()` method, which is inexact since KitKat, so you might have to wait a little while after the set time. You can change to `setExact()` for testing purposes, if you want. Lastly, keep in mind that you're setting the `Calendar` by the 24h clock.

Comment: As for the package, I added the package of my Service class in the manifest so I don;t think I need to have them i the same package anymore. I waited for a bit, nope the notification doesn't happen and if I change it to setExact that costs a minimum API level of 19. I've set mine to 16 right now. I don't want to increase the minimum level mate :/ How can I change the clock to 12h? :) @MikeM.

Comment: Change `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` to `Calendar.HOUR`, and un-comment the am/pm line. Also, I would suggest that you add some breakpoints or log prints in your code to make sure it's just the `Service` that's not running.

Comment: It worked! The Calender.HOUR change did the trick! Thanks so much @MikeM. If you can add that as an answer I can accept it

Comment: I just realised that it only works if I keep my screen on and also, no notification sounds come up when the notification happens @MikeM.

Comment: Yeah, you're not acquiring a `WakeLock` anywhere, so it's probably not gonna work when the screen is off. For that, you'll wanna implement either a [`WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) to start your `Service`, or use CommonsWare's [`WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) in place of your `Service`, if you don't want to add a Receiver. Also, you're not calling `setSound()` on your `Notification`, so it won't have a sound.

Comment: Thanks man! You were a great sport @MikeM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any `Service` used in your app must be listed in the manifest. Additionally, since your `Service` is to be used by only your app, setting the `exported` attribute to `false` is recommended.

For example, inside the `<application>` tags in the manifest:

```
<service android:name=".ReminderService"
    android:exported="false" />
```

Also, the `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` component on a `Calendar` sets the hour on a 24-hour clock. To use a 12-hour clock, use `Calendar.HOUR`, and set the `Calendar.AM_PM` component as well.

Finally, you'll want to somehow acquire a `WakeLock` to ensure that your `Notification` is issued even if the phone isn't active. In lieu of handing the `WakeLock` yourself, a couple of other options are available. The [`WakefulBroadcastReceiver` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) in the v4 support library can be used to start your `Service`, from which you can signal the Receiver to release the lock when done. Alternatively, you could simply replace your `Service` with [`CommonsWare`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)'s [`WakefulIntentService` class](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful), if you don't want to add a Receiver component.

If you choose to use the `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, you might still consider changing your `Service` to an `IntentService`, if it's not going to be doing any long-running operations, as an `IntentService` takes care of stopping itself when its work is done.